# PHPUnit installation

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm finally trying to integrate unit testing into my PHP work-flow, so I downloaded PHPUnit following [these instructions](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html), reproduced below:

```
➜ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

➜ chmod +x phpunit.phar

➜ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

However when I then tried to run a simple test case:

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest
```

I got the error `Cannot open file src/autoload.php`. I looked in the directory where I initially downloaded php and also in /user/local/bin/ but I don't see a `phpunit` folder or an `autoload.php` file anywhere. Where is this file, and how should I have known where it is? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change directory to your **Project Folder**. So if Your Project folder hierarchy is as follow:

```
->PhpProject
  ->>src
     - autoload.php
  ->>tests
     - MoneyTest.php
```

Then you should change current directory to PhpProject and then run your command.

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest
```

I assumed that you can actually find phpunit in `/usr/local/bin` if not try to install it again.

Comment: `Cannot open file "src/autoload.php"` - this error is being thrown when I run this ( `phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests` ) command from `PhpProject` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people having problems with installing and running phpunit. I use netbeans and git. Netbeans creates a testcase for you and runs it. Giving full reports about your tests. So if you don't know how to use the command lines install en download netbeans and run phpunit just like any other application.
 also visit this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it. 
Specify absolute path to your `autoload.php` for example `/srv/www/test/src/autoload.php`

Comment: `Cannot open file "src/autoload.php"` - this error is being thrown when I run this ( `phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests` ) command from `test` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your work-flow uses composer, you should install phpunit with it (composer install phpunit/phpunit), it will be easier.

After you will need to add an xml file for your test suite (at the root of your test folder for example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="../vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/*</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>tests</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>tests/fixtures</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

in bootstrap, you will have to specify the path of your autoload file

For running your tests :

./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml